# Recuperate the history of Internet Explorer V11 using command Prompt or

Tags: windows, cmd, internet-explorer-11, browser-history

I'm developing a C application that analyzes history of browsers (No Problem when analyzing chrome history) but i didn't find where Internet Explorer 11 stores its history  ,So, I want to recuperate the History using cmd (command Prompt ) . Can someone know the physical path where IE stores History .
Rq:ipconfig /displaydns doesn't solve my problem .

Comment: Please , Anyone know the answer .?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774957(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think that it cannot be usefull for windows 8.1 and IE V11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 10 the browsing history of IE 11 is named WebCacheV01.dat (I [read](https://cyberarms.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/windows-8-forensics-internet-cache-history/) that on Windows 8 it was named WebCacheV24.dat) and can be found here: `C:\Users\<USER NAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WebCache\`